# Nested contains statement

Tags: fortran

I have a program like this

```
program
    call one()
    contains one()
                 some vars
                 contains two()
                              use the vars of one
                              define its own vars
                              contains three()
                                           use the vars of both one and two
```

This doesn't compile because Fortran allows only the first contains statement.

I used this design to avoid passing and retyping all the variables of `one()` into `two()` and `three()`.

How can I rewrite the program so that the variable sharing is achieved?

I cannot define all the variable before the statement `call one()`.
The code will be to hard to manage, I need the feature :
`parent subroutine cannot access internal subroutine variables`.

Maybe a solution is to use pointer

```
call one(pointer_to_two)
```

then define the routine `two()` in its own module.
But I find this design complicate with my limited Fortran skills.
And I'm worried it will impact performance.

Should I use a `common block`?
I use the latest dialect of Fortran with the Intel compiler.

Below is 'compilable' example.

```
program nested_routines

    call one()

contains

    subroutine one()
        integer :: var_from_one = 10

        print *, 1
        call b()

        contains

            subroutine two()
                integer :: var_from_two = 20

                print *, 2, var_from_one
                call c()

            contains

                    subroutine three()
                        print *, 3, var_from_one, var_from_two
                    end subroutine

            end subroutine

    end subroutine

end module
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend placing your procedures (subroutines and functions) into a module after a single "contains" and using that module from your main program.   The local variables of each procedure will be hidden their callers.  The way that this differs from your goals is that you have to redeclare variables.   I dislike the inheritance of all variables in a subroutine contained in another because it is possible to mistakenly reuse a variable.    If you have a few variables that are shared across many procedures, perhaps the appropriate design choice is to make them global.  With Fortran >=90, a module variable is better method for a global variable than common blocks.  If you have variables that are communicated between a limited number of procedures, it is generally better to use arguments because that makes the information flow clearer.

Answer (score 2):

this might be possible if there is a separate module for each of the functions specific variables and a separate module for each function implementation

watch out for the order of the module compilation, according to the usage hierarchy necessity

also, i have no idea on the performance effect of doing this

```
module m1_var
  implicit none
  contains
end module m1_var
!========================================================================================================================
module m2_var
  implicit none
  contains
end module m2_var
!========================================================================================================================
module m3_var
  implicit none
  contains
end module m3_var
!========================================================================================================================
module m3_sub
  implicit none
  contains
  subroutine s3()
  use m2_var !to see varibles
  !arguments

  !local

  !allocation

  !implementation

  end subroutine s3
end module m3_sub
!========================================================================================================================
module m2_sub
  implicit none
  contains
  subroutine s2()
  use m3_sub
  use m1_var
  !arguments

  !local

  !allocation

  !implementation
    call s3
  end subroutine s2
end module m2_sub
!========================================================================================================================
module m1_sub
  use m1_var
  implicit none
  contains
  subroutine s1()
  use m2_sub
  !arguments

  !local

  !allocation

  !implementation
!    call s2
  end subroutine s1
end module m1_sub
!========================================================================================================================
program nestmoduse
  use m1_sub
  implicit none
  call s1
end program nestmoduse
```